# Translating Minecraft Color Codes into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors, minecraft

Recently, I was trying to convert Minecraft MOTD into Plain HTML. A Minecraft MOTD is basic text, with Minecraft Color Codes to represent color changes.

Example: "§d§lThe Nexus§8: §6§oO_O §a§l[MUTATION MONDAY]"

Translated: `<span style='color:pink'><b>The Nexus</b></span><span style='color:gray'>:</span>...`

So on... So basically, there are color codes, which change the color of the text onwards, and formatting codes, which change the formatting of the text onwards.

Now, because the Minecraft Color Codes do not state where the color codes end, I don't know exactly how I could translate this into HTML.

I did manage halfway, by replacing all color codes with `</span><span style='color:newcolor'>` and replacing all formatting codes with `</var><var style='text-decoration:blah'>`

This did not work however, because when you have a color code straight before a formatting code, it becomes `<span></var><var></span>`.

So the question is, how would I do this? Finding where the color codes end and so on.

Color Codes for Minecraft is available here: http://ess.khhq.net/mc/

Since my code is too big, I have it posted on JSFiddle.

My code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/thwe0yek/1/ (First one's fine, second one's messed up..)

Comment: Isn't this a question for [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I didn't think so. But maybe...

Comment: show us the rest of the "translated" markup for the example coded text. also, you can just use tag opens, you don't need to close the tag to get it to show up: the browser will make sense of what you meant and it should actually look ok with just openeings, as the colors will over-rule previous ones and they will all end at once. ugly over-nested markup, but it should look ok on the screen.

Comment: @dandavis Your method works, but I really want a clear mark-up, and I think that the answer from AlfonsoGarnett is the best. Thank you though, for your answer, and I might use it later on!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.

**A brief explanation of how this works:**

- It looks for all codes in the string with a regex that matches them (see the very first line in the `parseStyle` function)
- It pushes the indexes of where those codes are in the string into an array, and replaces each code with a double `\x00` (null char), in order to handle repetition of codes in later parts of the string (see the first `for` loop).
- It splits the string into parts, in accordance to the start of one code and the start of another, so that each part can be styled individually, with its own rules.
- Also in the second loop, the strings are sent to the `applyCode` function, which applies the codes given to it (through an array), with the help of the `styleMap`. This function creates a `span` element for each string it is given. If it finds the `k` rule, it will also apply the `obfuscate` function.
- The `obfuscate` function takes a string, gets its length, and generates a random character for every character in the string. It does this in an interval, char by char. The range of characters it chooses can be modified by changing the `randInt` values in the`replaceRand` function.
- Finally, the script returns an object with two properties: one is `parsed` which returns a DOM element with the 'obfuscators' running, and the other is `raw`, which returns the span elements as a HTML string (it's just `parsed`'s innerHTML).

To use it, just call `mineParse(string)`, for instance:

```
var result = mineParse('§6Hello');
document.body.appendChild(result.parsed);
```

**This now supports converting newlines to `<br>` tags, the `§r` reset code, and multiple codes applied in any order.**

I'm sure the script can be further simplified, though. Also, I'm sure it has bugs, you can modify it as you wish.

http://jsfiddle.net/fku9gsax/12/

```js
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var currId = 0,
        obfuscators = {},
        alreadyParsed = [],
        styleMap = {
            '§0': 'color:#000000',
            '§1': 'color:#0000AA',
            '§2': 'color:#00AA00',
            '§3': 'color:#00AAAA',
            '§4': 'color:#AA0000',
            '§5': 'color:#AA00AA',
            '§6': 'color:#FFAA00',
            '§7': 'color:#AAAAAA',
            '§8': 'color:#555555',
            '§9': 'color:#5555FF',
            '§a': 'color:#55FF55',
            '§b': 'color:#55FFFF',
            '§c': 'color:#FF5555',
            '§d': 'color:#FF55FF',
            '§e': 'color:#FFFF55',
            '§f': 'color:#FFFFFF',
            '§l': 'font-weight:bold',
            '§m': 'text-decoration:line-through',
            '§n': 'text-decoration:underline',
            '§o': 'font-style:italic'
        };

    function obfuscate(elem, string) {
        var multiMagic,
            currNode,
            listLen,
            nodeI;

        function randInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        function replaceRand(string, i) {
            var randChar = String.fromCharCode(randInt(64, 95));
            return string.substr(0, i) + randChar + string.substr(i + 1, string.length);
        }

        function initMagic(el, str) {
            var i = 0,
                obsStr = str || el.innerHTML,
                strLen = obsStr.length;
            if(!strLen) return;
            obfuscators[currId].push(
                window.setInterval(function () {
                    if (i >= strLen) i = 0;
                    obsStr = replaceRand(obsStr, i);
                    el.innerHTML = obsStr;
                    i++;
                }, 0)
            );
        }

        if (string.indexOf('<br>') > -1) {
            elem.innerHTML = string;
            listLen = elem.childNodes.length;
            for (nodeI = 0; nodeI < listLen; nodeI++) {
                currNode = elem.childNodes[nodeI];
                if (currNode.nodeType === 3) {
                    multiMagic = document.createElement('span');
                    multiMagic.innerHTML = currNode.nodeValue;
                    elem.replaceChild(multiMagic, currNode);
                    initMagic(multiMagic);
                }
            }
        } else {
            initMagic(elem, string);
        }
    }

    function applyCode(string, codes) {
        var elem = document.createElement('span'),
            obfuscated = false;

        string = string.replace(/\x00/g, '');

        codes.forEach(function (code) {
            elem.style.cssText += styleMap[code] + ';';
            if (code === '§k') {
                obfuscate(elem, string);
                obfuscated = true;
            }
        });

        if (!obfuscated) elem.innerHTML = string;

        return elem;
    }

    function parseStyle(string) {
        var finalPre = document.createElement('pre'),
            codes = string.match(/§.{1}/g) || [],
            codesLen = codes.length,
            indexes = [],
            indexDelta,
            apply = [],
            strSlice,
            i;

        if (!obfuscators[currId]) obfuscators[currId] = [];

        string = string.replace(/\n|\\n/g, '<br>');

        for (i = 0; i < codesLen; i++) {
            indexes.push(string.indexOf(codes[i]));
            string = string.replace(codes[i], '\x00\x00');
        }

        if (indexes[0] !== 0) {
            finalPre.appendChild(applyCode(string.substring(0, indexes[0]), []));
        }

        for (i = 0; i < codesLen; i++) {
            indexDelta = indexes[i + 1] - indexes[i];
            if (indexDelta === 2) {
                while (indexDelta === 2) {
                    apply.push(codes[i]);
                    i++;
                    indexDelta = indexes[i + 1] - indexes[i];
                }
                apply.push(codes[i]);
            } else {
                apply.push(codes[i]);
            }
            if (apply.lastIndexOf('§r') > -1) {
                apply = apply.slice(apply.lastIndexOf('§r') + 1);
            }
            strSlice = string.substring(indexes[i], indexes[i + 1]);
            finalPre.appendChild(applyCode(strSlice, apply));
        }

        return finalPre;
    }

    function clearObfuscators(id) {
        obfuscators[id].forEach(function (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        });
        alreadyParsed[id] = [];
        obfuscators[id] = [];
    }

    window.mineParse = function initParser(input) {
        var parsed,
            i = currId;
        if (i > 0) {
            while (i--) {
                if (alreadyParsed[i].nodeType) {
                    if (!document.contains(alreadyParsed[i])) {
                        clearObfuscators(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        parsed = parseStyle(input);
        alreadyParsed.push(parsed);
        currId++;
        return {
            parsed: parsed,
            raw: parsed.innerHTML
        };
    };

}());
```

```css
@media (max-width: 850px) {
   
   div#inBetween {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0.05em;
    }
    #inBetween:before {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family:'FontAwesome';
        content:"\f107";
        animation: bounceDown 2s infinite;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 850px) {
    #inBetween:before {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family:'FontAwesome';
        content:"\f105";
        animation: bounceRight 2s infinite;
    }
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:  100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
body {
    text-align: center;
    background: #050A0E;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#mainContainer {
  padding:  5em 0 5em 0;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5EB4E7;
    text-shadow: 0 0 50px #5EB4E7;
    padding: 1em;
    margin:  0;
    animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in-out;
}
#inputContainer, #outputContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 20em;
    height: 21em;
    background: #152E3D;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #5EB4E7;
    vertical-align: middle;
    animation: scaleIn 1s ease-in-out;
}
#inBetween {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #5EB4E7;
    font-size: 4em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    animation: scaleIn 1s ease-in-out;
}
#outputContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#inputContainer {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 20em;
    max-width: 20em;
    height: 20em;
    max-height: 20em;
}
#output {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.97);
    text-align: left;
    animation: bounceInRight 1s;
}
#output pre {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 4px solid #050A0E;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 20em;
    animation: bounceInRight 0.5s;
}
#input, #parse, #parse:active, #parse:focus {
    padding: 1em;
    width: 20em;
    background: #050A0E;
    color: #5EB4E7;
    outline: 0;
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
#parse {
    transition: all 225ms ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
#parse:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    background: #5EB4E7;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px #5EB4E7;
}
.containerLabel {
    position: relative;
    top: -0.5em;
    left: -1.5em;
    color: #5EB4E7;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0.85;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 40px #5EB4E7;
}
.bounceInRight {
    animation: bounceInRight 1s;
}
@keyframes bounceRight {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateX(-10px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateX(-5px);
    }
}
@keyframes bounceDown {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
    60% {
        transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
}
@keyframes bounceInRight {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(2000px);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(-30px);
    }
    80% {
        transform: translateX(10px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
@keyframes flipInY {
    0% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-10deg);
    }
    70% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
@keyframes scaleIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    80% {
        transform: scale(1.05);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
<script src="js/mine-parse.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainContainer">
  <h1> <i class="fa fa-code"></i> MineParse </h1>
  <div id="inputContainer">
      <div class="containerLabel">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil-square"></i>
          Input
      </div>
      <textarea id="input">
§nMinecraft Formatting

§r§00 §11 §22 §33
§44 §55 §66 §77
§88 §99 §aa §bb
§cc §dd §ee §ff
    
§r§0k §kMinecraft
§rl §lMinecraft
§rm §mMinecraft
§rn §nMinecraft
§ro §oMinecraft
§rr §rMinecraft
      </textarea>
      <button id="parse">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
          Parse
      </button>
  </div>
  <div id="inBetween"></div>
  <div id="outputContainer">
      <div class="containerLabel">
          <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
          Output <span id="parseTime"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="output"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
      (function () {
          'use strict';
          var input = document.getElementById('input'),
              output = document.getElementById('output'),
              parseBtn = document.getElementById('parse'),
              parseTime = document.getElementById('parseTime'),
              outputContainer = document.getElementById('outputContainer'),
              scrollInterval;
              
          parseBtn.onclick = function () {
              var scrollY = window.pageYOffset,
                  outputY = outputContainer.offsetTop,
                  parseStart = Date.now(),
                  result = mineParse(input.value);
              parseTime.innerHTML = '~ ' + ((Date.now() - parseStart) / 1000) + ' seconds';
              clearInterval(scrollInterval);
              output.innerHTML = '';
              if (window.innerWidth < 850) {
                  scrollInterval = setInterval(function () {
                      scrollY += 5;
                      window.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
                      if (scrollY >= outputY) {
                          window.scrollTo(0, outputY);
                          clearInterval(scrollInterval);
                      }
                  }, 0);
              }
              output.appendChild(result.parsed);
          };
      }());
  </script>
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly! Now I just have to comprehend this code... Also, how would you replace \n to <br>?    And a slightly different question. §k changes the text onwards until it hits a 'reset' to a random text, shifting every 0.1 second. Now, how could you possibly do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Yeah, analyze it a bit and improve it, it definitely could use some more stuff. To replace newlines you can use `/\\n/g` as a regex, along with the `replace` function; something like this: `string.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>');`. You should replace all newlines in the string before the for loops (because otherwise it'd mess up with the indexing of the codes). Hmm, as for that, it replaces every character it finds with a random char? And what is the `reset` character? Is the shifting visible? (As it is happening).

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Now, it's a little hard to explain the random character. It's shown on this image. http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/minecraft.gamepedia.com/7/7e/Minecraft_Formatting.gif?version=52b524e872522e7460ee8f833070785b . As for the reset character, every previous formatting is taken away.

Comment: No problem. I think I get it now. I've updated the code, this time it took me a while! I think it is now compliant with all of the rules. Check the update or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fku9gsax/12/). It got a bit more complex, but the approach to 'parsing' the codes is pretty much the same. The random character function is called obfuscate, it doesn't behave exactly the same as the one in Minecraft, but it can be modified so it does. Let me know if you need any further help. Good luck.

Comment: Aha. Your new code is fully comprehensible, plus, it works like a charm on my website! Thank you for all the help, time and effort you put in to this! I'm sure going to make amazing use of this, and will remember how, why, and who came up with this. :D

Comment: That's awesome to know. No problem, you don't have to remember all of that at all, ha. I'm just happy to hear that it'll be useful. This was fun! May everything go well with your site. : )